# Customizing Facebook Login button *USING JSSDK not FBML*

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I am using the Facebook Javascript SDK to create a login button using the following markup.

```
<div class="fb-login-button" data-show-faces="false" data-width="300px" 
     data-max-rows="1">Login with Facebook</div>
```

This works fine.  However, I want to customise this a little bit by making it larger.  I know this was possible using different values (`size=` for example) in the XFBML markup.  I've found the correct FB css classes that need to be applied by looking at the generated html so I can always hack it with some JQuery magic.

I would much rather just set the appropriate `data-*` attribute and have FB-JSSDK do it on its own.

*I've already tried `data-size=` which totally doesn't work*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just tried `data-size="large"`, and it worked. The style `fb_button_large` was applied to it, and it was slightly larger. It wasn't much larger though, I hardly noticed. Also, it's not documented so I assume it will be depreciated eventually?

`data-size="xlarge"` was NOTICEABLY larger, however.

```
<div class="fb-login-button" data-show-faces="false"
 data-max-rows="1" data-size="xlarge">Login with Facebook</div>
```

So, I'm not sure why it's not working for you. What I would do instead, then, is just use CSS if you want to fully customize the button.

The new button is just nested `<div class="fb-login-button"><a class="fb_button"><span class="fb_button_text">` DOM construct, and you can use CSS to style it however you want.

If you are having a cascading precedence issue with the Facebook styles taking over, just use `!important` at the end of your style declaration to override the Facebook ones.

You can even change the size of the "F" image, since it's a [sprite with multiple sizes](http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/yL/r/FGFbc80dUKj.png). When you override the styles, just play with the `background-position` property until you get the right one.

Good luck!

Comment: Could have been me.  I ended up using the `<fb:login-button>` tag with `size="xlarge"`;  Everything works properly now anyways.